# How to prevent Timer and Focus() from scrolling back the page up

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timer, textbox

So I have this timer inside an Update panel. It's used to add seconds on the page's clock. Also on the same page, on Page_Load, is a code to set focus on my textbox(TxtEmployee.Focus). Now before I added the  focus code the timer doesn't cause the page to scroll upward, as intended. When I added 'TxtEmployee.Focus' on Page_Load it causes to to scroll upward every second. I thought that the purpose of ScriptManager and Update Panel was to prevent my Timer from affecting the whole page. Is there a way to prevent the page from scrolling back up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UpdatePanels still execute the page lifecycle (including Page_Load). You should be able to achieve your required behaviour like so:

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    TxtEmployee.Focus
End If
```